# WooCommerce products sub category behave awkwardly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have run across an issue, I have added multiple parent and child categories. And set a menu for parent categories on the shop page. When user came and choose a parent category and select a child one of that. Then the page is redirected to shop page for a sec and then came up with the actual page. Behaving something like this as a user perspective.
Parent  -->   Child ----> (redirecting for few sec) Shop ---- > Child

Comment: If you go here http://www.wonderfulwonders.com.au/new/shop/ and pick BOYS and then any subcategory BOYS BY SIZE  see the URL and page behavior.

Comment: What is the reason for that loading? Why have you send ajax if finally you are redirecting it to that category page?

Comment: Stop that ajax loading on your page and it will automatically solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Logan, How to stop that ajax i am using a WordPress theme I haven;t done anything by custom coding. And i have used that theme for various site i am getting the issue on just this one.

Comment: Then maybe someone has done that ajax code on purpose, in some plugins or even done some customization on that theme or child theme. First try to detect which plugin is causing that by deactivating them and if still couldn't found anything then you have to go through your theme or child theme.

Comment: Hi Logan, Thanks a lot. Found it. Have a great day :)